# knockout binding is not working without parenthesis

Tags: knockout.js

I am somewhat new to knockout js. I have a button which is enabled or disabled based on an observable variable. 
It appears that the binding works only if I use it with a parenthesis.

anyone know why this happens? my understanding was that we should be able to bind the observable variables without parenthesis

```
self.noTaxResidencyChecked = ko.observable(false);

//works fine
<button data-bind="enable: !noTaxResidencyChecked()"></button>

//doesn't work
<button data-bind="enable: !noTaxResidencyChecked"></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

This comes down to the truthy(ness) of an object.  It is the default way things work in javascrpt.  When you use the '!' operator standard javascript comparison kicks in

var x = ko.observable(null);

!!x  // true - the observable itself is an object which evaluates to true
!!x() // false - you are now looking at the object inside the observable which is null, and evaluates to false

this is the same whenever you use the ! operator in the markup

```
// true if it evaluates to true
<button data-bind="enable: !noTaxResidencyChecked()"></button>

// true no matter what because the property is an observable object
<button data-bind="enable: !noTaxResidencyChecked"></button>
```

What you could possibly do

```
<button data-bind="disable: noTaxResidencyChecked"></button>
// since you are not using a '!' knockout does its standard look into the object
```

but that may not fit your needs